# Parsing URL into components

Tags: java, url

I want to parse a descriptive-style URL with slashes (such as `server/books/thrillers/johngrisham/thefirm`), in Java.

My overall idea is to handle the data I receive to do a lookup (therefore using the URL as search criteria) in a database and then return HTML pages with data on it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String urlToParse = "server/books/thrillers/johngrisham/thefirm";
String[] parsedURL = urlToParse.split("/");
```

What you will have is an array of strings that you can then work with.

```
// parsedURL[0] == "server";
// parsedURL[1] == "books";
// parsedURL[2] == "thrillers";
// parsedURL[3] == "johngrisham";
// parsedURL[4] == "thefirm";
```

Comment: Is there any objects I have to handle first? I'd like to accept this URL via a Tomcat server.

Comment: @myusername - Take a look at the URL class. There are different methods for retrieving specific parts of a URL.

Answer (score 3):

The [split() method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) of String class can do the work, as commented Ionut before.